# Two Sets of data in CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a CSV file which has two sets of data on the same sheet. I did my research and the closest I could find is what I have attached. The issue I am having is that both of them are not tables, their separate data sets; both of which are separated by a number of rows. I want to save each of the data sets as a separate CSV. Is this possible in Python? Please provide your kind assistance.

[Python CSV module: How can I account for multiple tables within the same file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820861/python-csv-module-how-can-i-account-for-multiple-tables-within-the-same-file)

First Set:

```
Presented_By:        Source:             City:
Chris                Realtor             Knoxville
John                 Engineer            Lantana
Wade                 Doctor              Birmingham
```

Second Set:

```
DriveBy               15
BillBoard             45
Social Media          85
```

My source is a Excel file which I convert into a CSV file.

```
import pandas as pd
data_xls = pd.read_excel('T:\DataDump\Matthews\REPORT 11.13.16.xlsm', 'InfoCenterTracker', index_col=None)
data_xls.to_csv('your_csv.csv', encoding='utf-8')

second_set = pd.read_csv('your_csv.csv',skiprows=[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,23])
```

Comment: Is the data always in the same place? If it is, use @kilojules' answer. If not, is there some way to easily detect when the second set starts? e.g. Two blank rows.

Comment: Can you add your source code to the question, so we can see what you have done?

Comment: I have updated my original post to reflect my code. Even after I edited my Python script it still shows up in the same format as it did when I first converted to CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `skiprows` in pandas' `read_csv`

```
$ cat d.dat
Presented_By:        Source:             City:
Chris                Realtor             Knoxville
John                 Engineer            Lantana
Wade                 Doctor              Birmingham
DriveBy               15
BillBoard             45
Social Media          85

In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: pd.read_csv('d.dat',skiprows=[0,1,2,3])
Out[2]: 
   DriveBy               15
0  BillBoard             45
1  Social Media          85

In [3]: pd.read_csv('d.dat',skiprows=[4,5,6])
Out[3]: 
      Presented_By:        Source:             City:
0  Chris                Realtor             Knoxv...
1   John                 Engineer            Lantana
2  Wade                 Doctor              Birmi...
```

You can detect what rows to skip by searching for when the csv has 2 entries not 3

```
In [25]: for n, line in enumerate(open('d.dat','r').readlines()):
    ...:     if len(line.split()) !=3:
    ...:        breakpoint = n
    ...:    
In [26]: pd.read_csv('d.dat',skiprows=range(breakpoint-1))
Out[26]: 
   DriveBy               15
0  BillBoard             45
1  Social Media          85

In [27]: pd.read_csv('d.dat',skiprows=range(breakpoint-1, n+1))
Out[27]: 
      Presented_By:        Source:             City:
0  Chris                Realtor             Knoxv...
1   John                 Engineer            Lantana
2  Wade                 Doctor              Birmi...
```

Comment: Thanks Kilojoules, the first set starts at the beginning so do not need to skip any rows there but the second set sets exactly after 14 rows.

Comment: @Pythoner I updated my answer to find the point where the file format changes